# why can I not parse variable parsed from outside?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to make a drop database script, which I would have to trigger using psql.

```
psql ... -f reset-database.sql -v dbname=$database
```

The problem is that I am not able to access the variable `:dbname` in my script.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT EXISTS( SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE datname = :dbname)) THEN
    UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = :dbname;
    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = :dbname;
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname;
   END IF;
END
$$
```

This is executed as is, and `:dbname` is not replaced with the database name parsed in as as variable? Why? And how do I parse it?

Answer (score 1):

The variable substitution will not work in a `DO` statement, because the statement body is a (dollar quoted) string literal. Otherwise, it should work fine, but you have to use single quotes in your metadata query. Besides, you cannot run `DROP DATABASE` inside a `DO` statement, since you cannot run it inside a transaction.

Also, **don't update catalog tables**.

You can use `psql`'s `\if` for conditional processing:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_database
   WHERE datname = :'dbname'
) AS have_db \gset
\if :have_db
ALTER DATABASE :dbname ALLOW_CONNECTIONS FALSE;
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
   FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = :'dbname';
DROP DATABASE :dbname;
\endif
```

From PostgreSQL v13 on, this is much simpler:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS :dbname WITH (FORCE);
```